# Why is .show() on a 20 row PySpark dataframe so slow?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using PySpark in a Jupyter notebook. The following step takes up to 100 seconds, which is OK.

```
toydf = df.select("column_A").limit(20)
```

However, the following `show()` step takes 2-3 minutes. It only has 20 rows of lists of integers, and each list has no more than 60 elements. Why does it take so long?

```
toydf.show()
```

`df` is generated as follows:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder\
    .config(conf=conf)\
    .enableHiveSupport()\
    .getOrCreate()
df = spark.sql("""SELECT column_A
                        FROM datascience.email_aac1_pid_enl_pid_1702""")
```

Comment: How is `df` generated? The `show()` is the only method here that actually *reads* any data... Note: *most applications are either CPU- or network-bound*, but only after the data is in memory

Comment: @cricket_007 updated. I thought df = spark.sql(. . .) might load/stream data into memory?

Comment: Nope. It was only loads metadata (as far as I know)

Comment: That is weird. I would say this could be a network bottleneck because it needs to load data from your executors. One dirty solution to solve the problem is to cache the toydf. So the first show will be slow but afterwards it should be loaded into memory.

Answer (score 2):

In spark there are two major concepts:

**1: Transformations:** whenever you apply withColumn, drop, joins or groupBy they are actually evaluating they just produce a new dataframe or RDD.

**2: Actions:** Rather in case of actions like count, show, display, write it actually doing all the work of transformations. and this all Actions internally call Spark RunJob API to run all transformation as Job.

And in your case case when you hit `toydf = df.select("column_A").limit(20)` nothing is happing.

But when you use `Show()` method which is an action so it will collect data from the cluster to your Driver node and on this time it actually evaluating your `toydf = df.select("column_A").limit(20)`.